# How to use Scalatra with Java8 LocalDateTime

Tags: scala, datetime, jackson, scalatra, json4s

We are using Scalatra 2.4 with JacksonJsonSupport 3.3 and are having problems serializing Java8 LocalDateTime.  It is failing with "No constructor for type LocalDateTime, JObject(List())"

I've tried a bunch of searches to find a resolution; with many references to using the JSR-310 ObjectMapper.  However, I have not found a way to use this mapper with Scalatra.

Could someone give a pointer on how to serialize Java8 datetime formats with Scalatra's Json support?

Thanks.

Here is what I hope is the relevant sections of the current code. I've included the swagger stuff just in case it is relevant.  If something else is needed let me know.

```
case class EchoPayload(
  message: String,
  author: String,
  createdAt: LocalDateTime
)

class EchoController(val dataSource: EchoDataSource) {
  def findById(echoId: Int): Try[EchoPayload] = {
    dataSource.findById(echoId).map { echo =>
      EchoPayload(echo.message, echo.author.getOrElse("anon"), echo.createdAt)
    }
  }
}

trait BaseRoute extends ScalatraServlet with JacksonJsonSupport with BaseSwagger {
  override protected implicit val jsonFormats = DefaultFormats.withBigDecimal

  before() {
    contentType = formats("json")
  }

  // Error handler, errors translated to Scalatra error ActionResults
  error {
    case bre: BadRequestException => BadRequest(ErrorPayload(bre))
    case nfe: NotFoundException => NotFound(ErrorPayload(nfe))
    case he: HttpException => InternalServerError(ErrorPayload(he))
    case NonFatal(e) => InternalServerError(ErrorPayload(e))
  }

}

class EchoRoute(val controller: EchoController) extends BaseRoute {

  val getEcho = apiOperation[EchoPayload]("getEcho")
    .summary("echo echo echo")
    .notes("returns an echo")
    .parameters(
      pathParam[Int]("echoId").description("id of the echo to return")
    )
    .responseMessages(
      messageOk("success"),
      messageBadRequest("invalid echo id"),
      messageNotFound("no echo yet"))

  get("/:echoId", operation(getEcho)) {
    val echoId = Try(params("echoId").toInt).getOrElse(throw new BadRequestException("echoId is required int"))

    controller.findById(echoId) match {
      case Success(payload) => Ok(payload)
      case Failure(e) if e.isInstanceOf[NoEchoException] => throw new NotFoundException(s"No echo at id=$echoId", e)
      case Failure(e) => throw e
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Added code as requested

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom serializer. Adding the following to your scope has worked for me:

```
 object LocalDateTimeSerializer extends CustomSerializer[LocalDateTime](format => (
{
  case JString(d) => LocalDateTime.parse(d, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
  case JNull => null
},
{
  case x: LocalDateTime => JString(x.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))
}
))

implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + LocalDateTimeSerializer`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) for the formatting. Have you looked at how they support [extensions](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extensions)? They don't appear to support Java8's `java.time` directly, but it should be pretty similar to [Joda](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.4/ext/src/main/scala/org/json4s/ext/JodaTimeSerializers.scala).